# Nginx running but not serving

Tags: http, nginx

I'm configuring a proxy pass for all HTTP traffic to port 9001.

**Nginx.conf**

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

#include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

  #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

**sites-available/itdb:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9001/;
    }
}
```

- I have verified the symlink between `sites-available` & `sites-enabled` is in tact and recognizing my config.
- I am getting no errors, and all `nginx-t tests` succeed without issue.
- I have tried with and without the trailing / on the proxy pass.

I'm a bit lost on what else to look for. Does anything stick out to you?

Comment: A dumb question, you dont happen to be in a network where port 80 inwards to the host is blocked, do you?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all, it wouldn't be out of the realm of possibility, let me verify, this server was just spun up so could be an oversight.

Comment: Nmap checks out for both 80 and 443.

Comment: On which OS is your nginx running?

Comment: What error do you get, when calling the nginx?

Comment: OS is CentOS, there are no errors presented anywhere. Even when testing the config, no errors prompt. This is from a clean install as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not much of an answer, but my solution was a fresh OS & Nginx install (even though these were already fresh). I'm not sure what was conflicting, but the moment I installed Nginx & copied my configs over, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: In comment to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701110/nginx-running-but-not-serving/54756989#54756989) you stated '[…]its possible someone did some tweaking before creating the image'. This sounds like docker. Were you probably using docker-compose to spin up the application? If so and given involvement of different private IP subnets on your side (e.g. VPN on top of dial-in) there is a slight chance of IP-address conflicts between addresses of docker's application-stack and the real-world ones. If the container still exists, you can inspect it to check ranges.

Answer (score 3):

You can verify whether nginx is running and binding to port 80 with something like [`lsof`](http://ports.su/sysutils/lsof) and/or [`fstat`](http://mdoc.su/o/fstat.1):

Here's `fstat` on OpenBSD:

```
% fstat -u www | fgrep "*:"
www      nginx      21404   82* internet stream tcp 0xfffffe833a10d250 *:80
www      nginx      21404   83* internet6 stream tcp 0xfffffe833a10d480 *:80
```

Here's `lsof` on GNU/Linux:

```
% lsof -i -n | fgrep nginx
nginx    24854        root    6u  IPv4 61955031      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx    25047      nobody    6u  IPv4 61955031      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Also, per https://serverfault.com/a/870709/110020, I would recommend against using the `sites-available`/`sites-enabled`, as it may also be giving you the extra hassles.

The next step would be to run [`curl -v`](http://ports.su/net/curl) from within the box where nginx is running, and/or involve [`tcpdump`](http://mdoc.su/o/tcpdump.8) to try to find where the packets are getting lost — perhaps you have a firewall in place?  Do you get any reply from nginx at all?  Is it perhaps your backend that's unavailable?

Comment: Nginx does not bind to the port, it doesn't seem like anything's working properly. Going to try a fresh install of OS and Nginx.

Comment: @CodeSpent, is it even running at all?  It sounds like it might not be running at all.

Comment: It is running without issue (as in the service is active with no failures), but not doing anything as far as I can see.

Comment: @CodeSpent how do you know it's running?  How do you start it?  What is it doing that makes you believe it's fully running without issues?

Comment: Systemctl starts it without issue, when asking for status it presents all Active/Success statuses. When using `nginx -t` its a complete pass.

Comment: @CodeSpent that's not the supported way of using nginx.  Have you tried starting it with `nginx`, as per https://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html?  What does `lsof -n | fgrep nginx` return?  (If it'll return nothing, it sounds like it's not running at all.)

Comment: I am aware of `lsof` but it didn't give me any details that matter outside what we already know. Nginx is running (service is active, nginx knows its started, and I have process IDs for workers), but not binding to any port. I have 8 processes for Nginx currently, a restart will spawn the same amount.

Comment: @CodeSpent possibly incorrect symlinks for sites-enabled in the old installation?

Comment: No those were all verified numerous times. Logs show my server was spun from a snapshot so its possible someone did some tweaking before creating the image.